# NextJS - How to get runtime environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, next.js

Noob question, my apologies.

I'm wondering if anyone knows the recommended deployment flow for NextJS self-hosted (e.g. docker or kubernetes). I'm doing a typical build once, ship per environment while changing environment variables to match the environment but keeping the image the same.

Since NextJS auto-opts-out of SSG when you use "getInitialProps" and "publicRuntimeConfig", I'm wondering, what's the best way to deploy the same image to multiple environments (again, self hosted on generic cloud e.g. docker run).

1. Do I have to always bake in the environment variables? So I have to build an image per environment, and per update to env vars.
2. Use publicRuntimeConfig / getInitialProps but forget about SSG optimisation, even if my variables are non-sensitive (e.g. GA_TRACKING_ID)
3. ... Is there anything else?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm wondering about the same too. Maybe is worth to try dotenv in next.config.js

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [react-env](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env) which does just that.

The idea is that react-env will generate for you an `__ENV.js` JS file with your environment variables, which you can then access on client side via the window or via the `env` helper, eg:

```
<small>
  Works in the browser: <b>{env("CRA")}</b>.
</small>
```

When using Docker, you may [set an entrypoint](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env#using-with-docker-entrypoint) that generates the required  `__ENV.js` when the container boots:

```
ENTRYPOINT yarn react-env --env APP_ENV
```

Comment: what about server side-only variables?

Comment: you might want to check the answer from @iamkirill https://stackoverflow.com/a/74246133/1010492

Comment: I also came accross [import-met-env](https://iendeavor.github.io/import-meta-env/guide/getting-started/introduction.html#guide) recently, which seems to achieve the same purpose and also works on server side. I haven't tried yet. but you should have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I will expand on @gyum-fox answer, because `react-env` docs wasn't up to date and couple of things took some time to figure out.

Next.js version: `12.2.5`

### Packages

In [`react-env` Next.js repo](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env/tree/master/examples/next.js) were used 2 packages: `react-env` and `@beam-australia/react-env`. I don't know what's the purpose of the former, I used the latter.

### "Isomorphic"

`react-env` claims it's isomorphic, but I can't manage to make it work server side. So here comes the changes to .env file

```bash
REGULAR_VAR=VALUE
NEXT_PUBLIC_REGULAR_VAR=$REGULAR_VAR
```

Some variables I used both on server and client, so to make it work:

- `REGULAR_VAR` was used on server, manages in `.env` file
- `NEXT_PUBLIC_REGULAR_VAR` was used on client like this: `env('REGULAR_VAR')` (note: `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix was removed). Manages in `__ENV.js` file

### Using the package

To use `__ENV.js` file in Next.js, place the following line in `_document.tsx`

```
<Script src="/__ENV.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

Note: while `__ENV.js` sits in `/public` directory, at run-time file will be in root, as every file of that directory will be

### Generating `__ENV.js` file

`react-env` command only needed to generate `__ENV.js`, so you can launch project:

```bash
# like this
npx react-env --prefix NEXT_PUBLIC -- node server.js
# or like this
yarn react-env --prefix NEXT_PUBLIC && node server.js
```

- `--prefix NEXT_PUBLIC`: `NEXT_PUBLIC` is the default for client side env vars
- `node server.js`: or `next dev` or any other command to launch the project

### Docker

I use [Dockerfile from Vercel example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) for deployment.
To generate `__ENV.js` file in container, change

```bash
RUN yarn build
```

to

```bash
RUN npx react-env --prefix NEXT_PUBLIC --path .env.production -- yarn build
```

Here, I added `--path .env.production` to use production env vars.

### Conclusion

That's it! Now you can change client env vars in `__ENV.js`, restart the
production server and new values will be applied.

Comment: Alternative to `@beam-australia/react-env`: https://github.com/expatfile/next-runtime-env (similar approach)

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented lib that does everything including hot ENV reloading, etc.
Works like a charm and we started to use it to simplify CI/CD and secrets storage for our projects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cuww/runtime-env

Answer (score -2):

A not optimal solution is to build the Next project at runtime of your container, that way you will be able to read environment variables at runtime.

This has (at least) two obvious downsides:

- slower startup
- larger image size

Example of `Dockerfile` with build at runtime:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

COPY ./public public
COPY ./src src
COPY .env.local .env.local
COPY next.config.js next.config.js
COPY package.json package.json
COPY tsconfig.json tsconfig.json
COPY node_modules node_modules

# Create and give access to folders and files that will be edited during build time
RUN mkdir -p .next
RUN touch next-env.d.ts

RUN chmod -R ugo+rwX .next next-env.d.ts

USER 1001

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT=8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npm run build && npm run start"]
```