# Problem using environment variables with Astro and Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, astrojs

I am trying to deploy an Astro application as part of a bigger setup in turborepo. The application uses server side rendering, and I am have deployed it to Google Cloud Run in a docker container.

When developing locally I can put this in my env file:

`PUBLIC_VALUE="https://example.com/example".`

And then when I need to make a request to the url in my application from the client side I can do the following from a .js file somewhere

```
const BASE_HOST = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_VALUE
export const BASE_URL = BASE_HOST
```

Then somewhere in a React component i might do this:

```
const response = await axios.post(${BASE_URL}/signin`, { emailAddress, password });
```

And it all all works very well when running locally with yarn run dev. However whern deoployed to Google Cloud run in a docker container I can see that the variable is undefined.

I am very used to using GoogleCloud Run. And I have sucesfully gotten my Astro application to run without any problems. Usually in Google Cloud I can set environmental variables in the Google Cloud Console, and then I can fetch them from my code with process.env. I am very used to doing thus with other applications. However when I try fetching my value with the above code "import.meta.env.PUBLIC_VALUE" is undefined at clientside. console.log() with the value clearly shows.

Why is it undefined?

I have included some more info on my setup below:

This is the content of astro.config.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import 'dotenv/config';
import node from "@astrojs/node";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), react()],
  output: 'server',
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone"
  })
});
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# The web Dockerfile is copy-pasted into our main docs at /docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker.
# Make sure you update this Dockerfile, the Dockerfile in the web workspace and copy that over to Dockerfile in the docs.

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
RUN yarn global add turbo

FROM base AS builder
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune --scope=admin-frontend --docker

# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
WORKDIR /app

# First install dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
RUN yarn install

# Build the project and its dependencies
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

# Uncomment and use build args to enable remote caching
# ARG TURBO_TEAM
# ENV TURBO_TEAM=$TURBO_TEAM

# ARG TURBO_TOKEN
# ENV TURBO_TOKEN=$TURBO_TOKEN

RUN turbo run build --filter=admin-frontend...

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 expressjs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 expressjs
USER expressjs
COPY --from=installer /app .

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000

CMD node ./apps/admin-frontend/dist/server/entry.mjs
```

As mentioned the project builds and runs smoothly, locally in docker, and on Cloud Run with this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots of suggestions from [Roopa M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18265570/roopa-m)
I ended up just accepting that there must be some weird bug between how Google Cloud Run handles environmental variables and Astro.

My workaround has been to just never use environmental variables client side. We can do this by fetching them serverside from process.env and then parsing them to the specific component client side. An example of a signup page using this can be seen here:

```
---
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils/api';
---

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <SignUp BASE_URL={BASE_URL}  client:load />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As can be seen the variable is just passed from serverside directly in the component.

Then in api.js its exported like this:

```
export const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL ?? process.env.PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL
```

It could be done in one step but having it in its own file makes it easier for me to handle some custom logic regarding the variable.

I have chosen to prioritise import.meta.env.PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL, because in other environments such running locally it actually works. So by using the nullish coalescing operator I fetch from import.meta.env if possible. That way in Google Cloud run it will just import from process.env since the other statement will return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following troubleshoot options:

1. Use `@beam-australia/react-env` to fetch ENV variables . You can follow this [documentation](https://dev.to/cormacncheese/how-to-access-env-variables-in-google-cloud-run-using-nextjs-2o8g).
2. Using a third-party library, such as react-env, as advised in: [NextJS - How to get runtime environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65521094/nextjs-how-to-get-runtime-environment-variables) and also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67327008/consume-cloud-run-environment-variables-inside-nextjs-app)

Also make sure `.env` files are not included in `.gitignore`

### Update

As per the [documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/configuring-astro/#environment-variables) and this [github thread](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/3897#issuecomment-1181381500). Before loading your other files, Astro analyzes configuration files. As a result, accessing environment variables that were set in`.env` files is not possible using `import.meta.env`.

> Astro evaluates configuration files before it loads your other files. As such, you can’t use `import.meta.env` to access environment variables that were set in `.env` files.
>
> You can use `process.env` in a configuration file to access other environment variables, like those set by the CLI.
>
> You can also use `Vite’s` `loadEnv` helper to manually load `.env` files.
>
> astro.config.mjs
>
> ```
> import { loadEnv } from "vite";
> const { SECRET_PASSWORD } = loadEnv(import.meta.env.MODE, >process.cwd(), "");
> ```

Comment: Suggestion 1 just gives me the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined` which is the same as if I used dotenv. Which actually also makes sense. 

Just to clarify I really hope that it is possuble to set the enviroment variables at runtime if possible, as that would make my deployment much easier. Therefore I hope I can set them through the Cloud Run Console. That would make it possible for me to use the same Dockerfile for all environments and handle the configuration when deploying.

Comment: I really do not understand how solution 2 can be used to get environment variables in Astro to be honest. Can you maybe clarify how this approach can be used?

Comment: @Graunephar I apologize for miscommunication. I updated my answer, Have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. As I understand [the github bug thread](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/3897#issuecomment-1181381500), that you mentioned, it only seems to concern getting environmental variables from import.meta.env in astro.config.ts. It mentions that specifically, and thats also in the example used. [the astro documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/environment-variables/) specifically mentions using import.meta.env to get environmental variables client side

Comment: I still think that @beam-australia/react-env seems promising, but I cant figure out from reading the documentation how to configure it to import  enviromental variables from Google Cloud Run, and using .env files to load locally. Maybe you can give me some advice?

Comment: @Graunephar Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69519341/18265570) will help you.