# Using docker runtime environment variables in NextJS with App router/server components?

Tags: docker, next.js, environment-variables

If you use Pages router in NextJS there are multiple ways to get environment variables at runtime (tools like [react-env](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env)/[next-runtime-env](https://github.com/expatfile/next-runtime-env), in addition to that envs are available in `getStaticProps` (read more in [Craigs Wardmans blog about NextJS + docker](http://www.craigwardman.com/Blogging/BlogEntry/ssg-isr-and-environment-variables-in-next-js-and-docker))).

But how to do this when you are using server components in [App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) (available from NextJS 13)?

It is possible to [build the NextJS project in the `ENTRYPOINT` of the Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247220/5550386), but I do not want the slow startup and large images. I guess a [search-replace approach](https://raphaelpralat.medium.com/system-environment-variables-in-next-js-with-docker-1f0754e04cde) would also work for App router, but that feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS 13, using the App router, components may be either server or client components, which are [rendered in separate environments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering).

You can access environment variables in both server and client components, but there are certain behaviours that you need to be aware of:

- Server components can access any environment variables.
- Client components can only access environment variables whose name begins `NEXT_PUBLIC_` ([documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)).
- Layouts are server components unless specified as client components by the string `"use client"` ([documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)).
- Environment variable values will be baked-in at build time unless:

  - The component is a server component, and
  - The component is dynamic (note `force-dynamic` in the example below). You can check whether a component is static or dynamic by observing the symbols to the left of the component in the build output. A circle `○` indicates a static component and a lambda `λ` indicates a dynamic component.

Thus, if you wish to access an environment variable at **run-time** in a **client component**, you must pass it somehow from a server component. For example, if you wish to have the majority of an application run in the client environment and for it to use a run-time environment variable, you can wrap the whole `body` element in a client component as shown below. You could then run any client code in the `ClientBody` component, for example adding the environment variable to a React Context.

`app/layout.jsx`:

```js
import ClientBody from "@/components/Body";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"
const myVar = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR;

export default function RootLayout ({
  children,
}) {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR, myVar);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <ClientBody
        myVar={myVar}
      >
        {children}
      </ClientBody>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`components/Body.jsx`

```js
"use client";

import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";

export default function ClientBody({
  myVar,
  children
}) {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR, myVar);

  return (
    <body>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </body>
  );
}
```

Supply your run-time value to Docker like so: `docker run -e NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR="..." ...`

In the console output of the example, you will see that the value of `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR` will appear frozen at build-time in the client component, yet the value of prop `myVar` will be that of the run-time environment.